# Converting nvarchar type to numeric sql in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have this SP.

```
USE [Invoice]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInvoiceLines]
( @InInvoiceNbr int
 ,@InLinesPerPage   int
)
AS
DECLARE @TotalRows int
DECLARE @Remainder int
DECLARE @NumPages int
DECLARE @NextPageRows int
set @TotalRows= 0
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, InvProduct))as InvoiceRow,
                                             CoID,
                                             InvNo,
                                             InvProduct,
                                             InvDesc,
                                             InvQuantity,
                                             InvUOM,
                                             InvUnitPrice,
                                             InvAmt

into #tempInvoice
FROM Invoice_Products



SET @TotalRows= @@ROWCOUNT
IF @TotalRows=0
    BEGIN
        WHILE @TotalRows < @InLinesPerPage -- Add Blank Rows will generate blank invoice.
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalRows= @TotalRows+1
                INSERT  #tempInvoice
                 (InvoiceRow,
                 CoID,
                 InvNo,
                 InvProduct,
                 InvDesc,
                 InvQuantity,
                 InvUOM,
                 InvUnitPrice,
                 InvAmt
                 )
                 VALUES 
                 (@TotalRows
                 ,@InInvoiceNbr
                 ,''
                 ,''
                 ,0
                 ,0
                 ,0
                 ,''
                 ,0
                 ,0)
            END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Remainder =  @TotalRows%@InLinesPerPage -- get remainder
        IF @Remainder !=0 
        BEGIN
            -- Get the current page increase by 1 becasue we have a remainder.
            SET @NumPages = @TotalRows/@InLinesPerPage  +1 
            SET @NextPageRows = @NumPages * @InLinesPerPage
            WHILE @TotalRows < @NextPageRows -- Add Blank Rows
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalRows= @TotalRows+1
                INSERT  #tempInvoice
                (InvoiceRow,
                 CoID,
                 InvNo,
                 InvProduct,
                 InvDesc,
                 InvQuantity,
                 InvUOM,
                 InvUnitPrice,
                 InvAmt
                )
                VALUES 
                (@TotalRows
                ,@InInvoiceNbr
                ,''
                ,''
                ,0
                ,0
                ,0
                ,''
                ,0,
                0)
            END
        END
    END
SELECT * from #tempInvoice order by InvoiceRow asc
return
```

The problem is that when calculating the row number, **InvProduct** is nvarchar datatype. So, I am having error when I use this in RDL file. 
[image]
Can I have some idea/insight how to solve this?

P.S I have to use this SP in order to display invoice type report by following this:
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/use-sql-server-reporting-services-to-generate-an-invoice-document/

Comment: What is in **InvProduct**? can it be converted to *int*?

Comment: @Stephen InvProduct is nvarchar type

Comment: yes but since you are converting it to *INT* does it contain integer values or is it string? obviously if it is string values then you cannot use CONVERT to INT on it. Why are you trying to convert a varchar field to INT?

Comment: It is String. I am aware that(unless it is smallint or begin). But i hope i could find any work around? As in I could maintain the layout from SQL side?

Comment: so why not use *OVER( ORDER BY InvProduct)*? otherwise, if you want to use the ID, then join to the Product table and get the PRODUCTID

Comment: @Stephen I've changed to OVER( ORDER BY InvProduct) But, I am getting this error when I use it inside my RDL.  "An error occurred during report processing. Query execution data type varchar to numeric" For option 2, I don't have ProductID.

Comment: run the stored proc separately and see where the error is raised

Comment: Check your *#tempInvoice* Inserts as well, number of columns and values don't match

Comment: yep, after checking and correcting the whole sp, (esp to those #insert columns and datatype) I am able to ru the SP. Thanks.However my design has error  .

Comment: cool. it does help to mention the error

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm **InvDesc** is nvarchar datatype or int type? if it's nvarchar datatype then please use '' instead of 0.

Comment: Yes, I can just simply use OVER( ORDER BY InvProduct)